CSS grid - have one row not contribute to width of column, resulting in wrap
I want every "cell" in my grid to contribute to the column widths, except for a particular one - I want it to expand its height to contain (forcing a word wrap). Is there a way to do this?


body{
  display:flex;
}

.grid-container{
 display: grid;
 gap: 20px;
 grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
 .see-all{
   display: grid;
   grid-column-start:1;
   grid-column-end:4;
   grid-template-columns:subgrid;
   :nth-child(1){
     column:1;
   }
   :nth-child(2){
     column:2;
   }
   :nth-child(3){
     column:3;
   }
  }
  .other{
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  }
}
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
   <div class="see-all">
      <div>Apple</div>
      <div>Banana</div>
      <div>Coconut</div>
    </div>
    <div class="see-all">
      <div>Date</div>
      <div>Eggplant</div>
      <div>Fig</div>
    </div>
    <div class="other">
This row is just too long, I was this to use the width of the column (set by other elements) to then cause this to word wrap.
    </div>
  </div>
<body>




This is totally doable, but are you sure you want it to not contribute to the grid at all? This means the first column's width will be very short (based on "Apple", "Date") causing the sentence to wrap at pretty much every single word.

A contrived example :D.

would be beneficial to add a picture of the desired outcome

The min-width:100%; width:0 trick will do in your case. The grid track sizes are calculated based on its width, then its size will be grown back based on the size of the track because of min-width.


body {
  display: flex;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 20px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  .see-all {
    display: grid;
    grid-column-start: 1;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    grid-template-columns: subgrid;
     :nth-child(1) {
      column: 1;
    }
     :nth-child(2) {
      column: 2;
    }
     :nth-child(3) {
      column: 3;
    }
  }
  .other {
    grid-column: 1 / span 3;
  }
  .long-cell {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 0;
  }
}
<body>
  <div class="grid-container">
    <div class="see-all">
      <div>Apple</div>
      <div>Banana</div>
      <div>Coconut</div>
    </div>
    <div class="see-all">
      <div>Date</div>
      <div>Eggplant</div>
      <div>Fig</div>
    </div>
    <div class="other long-cell">
      This row is just too long, I want to force the elements in this row to word wrap and not contribute to the grid
    </div>
  </div>

  <body>




Perfect, thanks! This seems like a hack - is this how the behavior is defined to work or is it just fortunate that it works this way.

I'm not sure how well defined it is but I don't think this behavior will go anywhere since this trick is pretty commonly used in flex/grid for similar issues such as ignoring image width. In this case you probably don't want to use contain:size because it removes the height. (Unless you have a known max-height then you can combine the use of contain-intrinsic-size)

and I am giving a similar example using CSS grid in that answer so better vote to close as duplicate instead of repeating the same thing

That's true, thanks for pointing out. @bobthemagicmoose as stated in the post contain:inline-size would do the same.
